# Adaptive cards not rendering in the Microsoft BOT framework

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

Following is my code:

````
> To learn more Adaptive Cards format, read the documentation at
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots
- ```{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
              {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Please input ClientId, RequestId, TimeStamp, name of your Team",
                  "weight": "bolder",
                  "size": "medium",
                  "style": "heading",
                  "wrap": true
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Please also upload the ESRP Logs and your build logs after creating ticket to the Portal.",
                "isSubtle": true,
                "wrap": true
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.Text",
                "label": "Your Onboarding ClientId",
                "id": "ClientId",
                "validation": "^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$",
                "error": "Please enter your ClientId in the specified format",
                "isRequired": true                        
              },
              {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "RequestId",
              "label": "RequestId",
              "validation": "^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$",
              "error": "Please enter a valid RequestId"
              },
              {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "TimeStamp",
              "label": "TimeStamp"   
              },
              {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "TeamName",
              "label": "TeamName"   
              }
            ],
  "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit"
              }
            ]
}```
````

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework and Adaptive cards, want to create a form to take some inputs and parse it, want to validate the input and then submit to an API but it doesn't work in the adaptive cards no matter what i try. I also copied code from here
[AdaptiveCardInputForm](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/InputForm.html)https://adaptivecards.io/samples/InputForm.html
, not sure what i am doing wrong to render the adaptive card.

For some reason it just never renders in the bot. I fixed the json by formatting it, i have also it shows up at the UI like blank page:

[image]

Comment: While rendering cards, have you checked the log if there are any errors encountered? In addition, if you paste your card in adaptivecard.io site is that rending as expected?

Comment: i am trying to use the similar code from the adaptivecard.io site. It works fine on the site, but in the microsoft bot framework composer it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of back and forth trying and failing i am able to get this code working but still not able to include validation to the text boxes.

````
> To learn more Adaptive Cards format, read the documentation at
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots
- ```{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
              {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Please input ClientId, RequestId, TimeStamp, name of your Team",
                  "weight": "bolder",
                  "size": "medium",
                  "style": "heading",
                  "wrap": true
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Please also upload the ESRP Logs and your build logs after creating ticket to the Portal.",
                "isSubtle": true,
                "wrap": true
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.Text",
                "placeholder": "Your ClientId (you can find this info at the https://aka.ms/esrpportal)",
                "id": "ClientId",
                "validation": {
                "errorMessage": "Please enter your ClientId in proper GUID format",
                "necessity": "required"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.Text",
                "placeholder": "RequestId",
                "id": "RequestId",
                "validation": {
                "errorMessage": "Please enter your RequestId in proper GUID format",
                "necessity": "required"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.Number",
                "placeholder": "What is the severity of your incident (Defaults to sev3)?",
                "id": "Severity"
              },
              {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "TimeStamp",
              "placeholder": "TimeStamp"
              },
              {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "TeamName",
              "placeholder": "TeamName"   
              }
          ],
  "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit"
              }
            ]
}```
````

Comment: it seems there are some issues with Adaptive cards in Bot: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9680